# no scrolling image background on a fixed height container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.2.
I have a container with a fixed height (based on user window height) and scrollbar-y activated for it.

The problem is coming from the container's image background: it's acting as fixed even if i have set it up as scroll.

Here is my CSS:

```
html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#tb1 {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#tb2 {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;
}
#container {
    /*overflow-y:hidden;
    height:400px;*/
    background:url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat scroll transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#row1 {
    padding:10px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//cdn.a973c.com/scripts/bootstrap/2.2.2/bootstrap-2.2.2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//cdn.a973c.com/scripts/bootstrap/2.2.2/bootstrap-responsive-2.2.2.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="tb1">tb1</div>
        <div id="tb2">tb2</div>
        <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid" id="row1" style="height:1500px;">
                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

                 <h1>content</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

And a [jsFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/A973C/hbJqm/1/)

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: When I unset height for #row1, my background is scrolling correctly...

Comment: `background:url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat scroll transparent;` in this i think `350x150` is a image with no extension what abou the **.png** **.jpg** **.gif** ?

Answer (score 0):

Error code is :

```
 background:url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat scroll transparent;//No .png provied
```

The file's extension is not provied in your css.  it should like below

**Correct code**

```
background:url(http://placehold.it/350x150.png) repeat scroll transparent;
```

as i seen i just tried with the `.png` extension it works you need to specify which type of file by the extension

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish/hbJqm/4/)

Comment: Thank you krish but the background is still fixed. I need it to scroll with content.

Comment: @Arnaud : change the `no-repeat` to `repeat` as i changed in my answer now

Comment: I don't want a repeted background but just to prevent it from being fixed! Sorry if my question is not clear (english is not my native language).

Comment: Thank you for trying to solve my issue, I appreciate :-) However the bug is with my actual configuration not with an other one!

Answer (score 0):

Adding **"background-attachment: local"** should fix your problem:

```
#container {
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:400px;
    background:url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat transparent;
    background-attachment: local;
    top:70px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#row1 {
    padding:10px;
    max-height:100%;
}
```